# Echo the subtitle of a PARENT page within WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, subtitle

I'm attempting to fetch the subtitle from the PARENT page and echo the text within a title tag.

**Function:**

```
<?php
    $id_to_get = $post->ID;
    if ( $post->post_parent ) {
        $id_to_get = $post->post_parent;
    }
    $parent = $id_to_get;

    $title = get_the_title($parent);
    $subtitle = get_post_meta($id_to_get, '_base_page_subtitle', true);
?>
```

**HTML Implementation:** ...title="<?php echo $subtitle; ?>">

Unfortunately, it is not successfully grabbing the subtitle text.  I'm able to populate the title echoing the variable $title, just not with the variable $subtitle.

The value for the Subtitle option is stored within the table "_base_page_subtitle"; I'm using options framework.

I know my issue is with the if statement, however, being new to PHP, I'm having a bit of difficulty figuring out how to capture the data and display it properly.

Thanks again of time!

Comment: Does `$post` have a `$post_child` property? I think you can just check if `$post->post_parent` and then set it to `$post->post_parent`. If a post doesn't have a parent, I believe that is set to zero.

Comment: Using post_parent, unfortunately, still does not populate it with the subtitle text...

Comment: Does the `$id_to_get` get set correctly if you echo it out?

Comment: It does, in this instance, it will echo out "67" properly in the title tag.

Also, I updated the original code snippet to use post_parent instead of post_child. I forgot to update that before I submitted the post as I was troubleshooting still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it without a function - just echo it straight out

```
title="<?php if ( $post->post_parent ) { echo get_post_meta($post->post_parent, '_base_page_subtitle', true);}else{echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_base_page_subtitle', true);}?>"
```

Comment: Mark,
This works great for the child pages, however, it no longer displays the title on the actual parent page.  This also puts the page-title/sub-title in the title tag.

Comment: I need it to display the subtitle as the title tag on the parent page and all child pages of that parent.

Comment: so you want just the subtitle in the title tag on both parent and child?

Comment: That is correct Mark.  I tried doing that with the if statement, unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: Thanks Mark! You rock. Now I'll have to wrap it in a variable to simplify the process. Have any suggestions on the best method of doing this?

Comment: what do you mean? how will it simplify it?

Comment: Echoing a variable is the system the previous developer had in place and he located all the functions associated with the variables at the top of the document. So, in theory, everything "technical" lived at the top of the .php document and any references that existed after the functions were all echos.

Comment: try adding it to a function

Comment: Mark, can you check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218051/echo-the-subtitle-of-a-parent-page-within-wordpress-part-2