# Echo the subtitle of a PARENT page within WordPress - Part (2)

Tags: php, wordpress

**Original topic:** [Echo the subtitle of a PARENT page within WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18089543/)

I've discovered a separate need for the code Mark produced in relation to the original topic above.  Luckily, I was able to work with another community member to achieve a similar function to handle the href for the same element this question will relate too.

I need to have the title tag populate based off the subtitle value of the parent page. However, if no parent is set, I need it to default to the default subhead of the entire site.

We were able to achieve this for the href attribute here: [How to set a link based off a post_parent being set - WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18212283/)

**The current code is handled this way:**

```
<?php
    if ($post->post_parent) {
        $permatitle = get_post_meta($post->post_parent, '_base_page_subtitle', true);
    } else {
        $permatitle = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_base_page_subtitle', true);
    }
?>

<a href="<?php echo $permalink; ?>" title="<?php echo $permatitle; ?>">
```

However, I need it to work on child pages as well. Any help would be appreciated and I'll upvote anyone that can contribute to solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are trying to achieve the same thing ([refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212283/how-to-set-a-link-based-off-a-post-parent-being-set-wordpress)) but this time for the title,

**you can do this:**

```
<?php
if ($post->post_parent!=0) {
    // for child pages
    $permatitle = get_post_meta(end( get_ancestors( get_the_ID(), 'page' )), '_base_page_subtitle', true); 
} elseif($post->ID==0||count(get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID))==0) { 
    //for HP or pages with no child
    $permatitle = get_post_meta(get_option( 'page_on_front' ), '_base_page_subtitle', true); 
} else { 
    // for top level pages/parents
    $permatitle = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_base_page_subtitle', true); 
}
```

**or better yet, combine the two:**

```
<?php 
if ($post->post_parent!=0) {
    // Handling of Child Pages
    $permalink = get_permalink( end( get_ancestors( get_the_ID(), 'page' )));
    $permatitle = get_post_meta(end( get_ancestors( get_the_ID(), 'page' )), '_base_page_subtitle', true); 
} elseif($post->ID==0||count(get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID))==0) {
    // Homepage or Pages with no Parent
    $permatitle = get_post_meta(get_option( 'page_on_front' ), '_base_page_subtitle', true);
    $permalink = home_url();
} else { 
    // Handling of Top Level/Parent Pages
    $permatitle = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_base_page_subtitle', true);
    $permalink = get_permalink( end( get_ancestors( get_the_ID(), 'page' )));
}
```

**then you can do this after:**

```
<a href="<?php echo $permalink; ?>" title="<?php echo $permatitle; ?>">
```

Comment: This is 90% there. Unfortunately, if I navigate to a child page of a parent, it is populating the title tag with the global title instead of the parent title.

Comment: Meaning if I navigate to root/parent-page/child-page, even though child-page has the parent-page set to the parent in the properties, the global root Subtitle is displaying instead of the parent Subtitle.

Comment: all i did was get the title of the specific pages you were taking the permalinks from..

Comment: I think it is missing a step where it's grabbing the wrong Subtitle attribute.  I can attempt to look into it further.

Comment: can you go back to chat?

Comment: Sure, however, I have no clue how to initiate it.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35371/discussion-between-joey-odriscoll-and-reikyoushin

Comment: This worked great! I combined the two scripts you worked with me on yesterday here: http://pastebin.com/R4dnmATt

Comment: cool! i will update my answer now.. and another bonus, this is way cleaner than the code before ;)

Comment: Reik, could you check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318168/handling-of-back-to-home-population-with-php-in-wordpress, I'm in need of a bit of help again :\